# "JSON Parsing ending with unexpected character" when using DeserializeJSON on JSON.stingify value

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion-10

My application contains multiple `<input type="file">` fields and I need to save the file paths.  I am converting the paths into a JSON string and sending the result to a ColdFusion CFC method. On the ColdFusion side I am deserializing the JSON string using `DeserializeJSON()`, but am getting an error:

> JSON Parsing ending with unexpected character

.

I had the same issue when passing a serialized FORM structure into a ColdFusion page. I fixed it by URL encoding the value with `URLEncodedFormat()`. Would url encoding the above JSON string fix this issue or is my code for passing the file paths as a JSON string incorrect?

My client side code is below:

```
var lttr_docs = {};
for(i=1;i<length;i++)
{
    lttr_docs['file_id_'+i] = $('#file_id_'+i).val();
}

$.ajax({
    url: "xyz/component.cfc?method=methodName",
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    data: JSON.stingify(lttr_docs),
    success: function(res)        {
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);                
    }
});
```

Basically the problem is while desrializing the JSON string in server side. Can I do some thing on client side to fix this or do I need to completely rely on a server side fix?

Answer (score 1):

`dataType` is not for telling the server what kind of data you're sending it, even though `data` is for the data you're sending; it's just one of the flaws in the jQuery API. Counter-intuitively, `dataType` is for telling jQuery what kind of data you expect *back*. So `dataType: "json"` is probably wrong. Instead, you want `contentType: "application/json"`.

So your `GET` is getting sent to the server with the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` content type, which is probably confusing it.

Separately, as Rocket Hazmat points out in a comment below, specifying the content type on a `GET` is a bit fishy. You probably want to change this to a `POST` (both in the client code and the server code processing it).

Comment: Can you use `contentType` with a `GET` request?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Good catch, I didn't notice until adding the second paragraph it was a `GET`. I don't think you can, no, but I don't use `GET` for sending data to servers so I don't know the ins and outs of it... I'll add a note.